# Is there way to convert 1 element of string to multiple as desired

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

https://code.sololearn.com/cRcr0h9XTJt0/?ref=app

```
     arr =["(2,2),(2,2),(2,2),(2,2)"]
     print(len(arr))
     outputrequired = []
     outputrequired = [[2,2],[2,2],[2,2],[2,2]]
     print(len(outputrequired)
```

1. Here i need to covert "arr"         into "outputrequired"

Answer (score 0):

Your `arr` is a list with only one element: a string. Using [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval) to parse this may seem like a good option, but to parse this safely you should use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval).

Now, if we do this:

```
from ast import literal_eval

arr = ["(2,2),(2,2),(2,2),(2,2)"]
evaluated = literal_eval(arr)
print(evaluated)
```

...we get an error:

```
ValueError: malformed node or string: ['(2,2),(2,2),(2,2),(2,2)']
```

`arr` isn't a string, but converting `arr` to a string and passing it to `literal_eval` works, but it doesn't do anything, and just returns back the same `arr`

What we need to do is convert the first (and only in this case) element of `arr` to a list of tuples, instead of the string that it currently is.

So we pass `arr[0]` to `literal_eval`, which returns this:

```
from ast import literal_eval

arr = ["(2,2),(2,2),(2,2),(2,2)"]
evaluated = literal_eval(arr[0])
print(evaluated)
```

```
((2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2))
```

A [tuple](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuples) of tuples. We're getting close. To convert tuples to strings, we just do this:

```
list(tuple)
```

Our list of tuples is stored in the variable `evaluated`, so to convert it to a list, we do this:

```
list(evaluated)
```

...which returns this:

```
[(2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2), (2, 2)]
```

Even closer. To convert the tuples within `evaluated` to lists, we can use list comprehension:

```
outputrequired = [list(t) for t in evaluated]
```

This basically translates to:

```
outputrequired = []
for t in evaluated:
    outputrequired.append(list(t))
```

It's just a more efficient way.

Anyways, here's the result of `outputrequired`:

```
[[2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2]]
```

A list of lists.

Full code:

```
from ast import literal_eval

arr = ["(2,2),(2,2),(2,2),(2,2)"]

evaluated = literal_eval(arr[0])
evaluated = list(evaluated)

outputrequired = [list(t) for t in evaluated]

print(outputrequired)
```

[Run and edit this code online](https://repl.it/@marsnebulasoup/NegativeCleanTrialsoftware#main.py)